# NoSuchMethodError org.apache.commons.collections.ExtendedProperties.getList(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List in Struts 2

Tags: java, maven, struts2, tiles, tiles-3

I want to use Tiles 3 with Strut 2 so I'm using `struts2-tiles3-plugin`. I've defined the listener in `web.xml` and the result-type in `struts.xml`. When I deploy the war Tomcat returns a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`.

**This is my `web.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID"
        version="3.0"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>MyProject</display-name>

    <!-- tiles listener -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- my listener -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.myproject.MyListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**This is my `struts.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>


    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">

        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"/>
        </result-types>

        <action name="">
            <result type="redirectAction">home</result>
        </action>

        <action name="home" class="com.myproject.action.Homepage" method="execute">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">jsp/home.jsp</result>
            <result name="login">jsp/Login.jsp</result>
        </action>

        ...

    </package>

</struts>
```

**This is my `tiles.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="baseLayout" template="/jsp/layouts/base.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="MyProject" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/jsp/layouts/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/jsp/layouts/content.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/jsp/layouts/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="home" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="MyProject Home" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/tiles/home-body.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

**And this is my `pom.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

 <!-- General Info -->
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>MyProject</name>

<!-- Properties -->
<properties>
    <struts2.version>2.3.16.3</struts2.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<!-- Dependencies -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>${struts2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-config-browser-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${struts2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-junit-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-tiles3-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

</project>
```

**Tomcat (v. 7.0.39) return this error:**

```java
lug 06, 2014 8:16:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAZIONI: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
lug 06, 2014 8:16:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.collections.ExtendedProperties.getList(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List;
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.view.VelocityView.configure(VelocityView.java:368)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.view.VelocityView.init(VelocityView.java:342)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.view.VelocityView.init(VelocityView.java:310)
    at org.apache.velocity.tools.view.VelocityView.<init>(VelocityView.java:213)
    at org.apache.tiles.velocity.renderer.VelocityAttributeRenderer.commit(VelocityAttributeRenderer.java:82)
    at org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesContainerFactory.registerAttributeRenderers(CompleteAutoloadTilesContainerFactory.java:168)
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createRendererFactory(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:411)
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createContainer(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:111)
    at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.createContainer(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:124)
    at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.initialize(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:70)
    at org.apache.tiles.web.startup.AbstractTilesListener.contextInitialized(AbstractTilesListener.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1462)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor33.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:677)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:435)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: `commons-collections-3.1.jar` is missing in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder or add from maven

Comment: @prash That wasn't an appropriate edit, and actually made parts of it worse.

Comment: lemme compare mine with ur edit and will learn from the difference. Thanks for the comment @DaveNewton

Comment: @DaveNewton : These are the errors that I found with the edit diff - (1) Made the error log as a block instead of code. (2) Some of the technology keywords like web.xml, struts.xml were italicized (3) edited strut2 to Struts2 [this is correct though].. But thank you for pointing out, will not repeat.

Comment: @prash The code block was the worst part; the rest were simply too minor, although the spelling correction is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a version conflict between velocity and commons-collections. Note that in the version of struts you use it requires velocity 1.6.4 which depends on commons-collections 3.2.1. On the other side tiles plugin still requires commons-collections 3.2.

You can run `mvn dependency:tree` to view what dependencies are resolved or in the IDE look at effective POM.

Comment: To get around this, use your IDE or change your pom.xml to include a dependencyManagement section to specify which version of commons-collections, struts, and tiles you want to use.